# Calling a double instance_method with different parameters

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm testing some code that calls the aws-sdk (v2). Many of the methods do pagination by setting a `is_truncated` attribute in the returned value. You then use other values in the return (often `marker`) and pass it into the next invocation. So, the usage will often look something like:

```
values = []
rv = client.do_thing
values.concat rv.things
while rv.is_truncated
    rv = client.do_thing(next_marker: rv.marker)
    values.concat rv.things
end
```

My question is this - I want to `instance_double` the AWS client. But, I can't find a way of saying "Expect the first call to have no parameters and return `this`. Then, the second call will have `these` parameters and return `that`." I know I can set the return values of both calls by putting both expected `rv`'s in the same `and_returns()` call. But, I want to test that the `marker` from the first `rv` is passed as the `next_marker` in the next call.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Message Order`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/setting-constraints/message-order) feature in `RSpec mocks`:

```
RSpec.describe "Constraining order" do
  it "passes when the messages are received in declared order" do
    collaborator_1 = double("Collaborator 1")
    collaborator_2 = double("Collaborator 2")

    expect(collaborator_1).to receive(:step_1).ordered
    expect(collaborator_2).to receive(:step_2).ordered
    expect(collaborator_1).to receive(:step_3).ordered

    collaborator_1.step_1
    collaborator_2.step_2
    collaborator_1.step_3
  end
end
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't point out that this is the only way to do this for different sets of parameters.